# Avalonia UI ListBox Styles Data Binding with Reactive UI

Tags: listbox, listboxitem, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am creating an Avalonia ListBox with Avalonia 11.0, and trying to enable or disable ListItem programmatically using ReactiveUI. I have binded AvaloniaList<> to the ListBox. But I am unable to bind the ViewModel to  <ListBox.Styles> Setter and {Binding IsEnabled} is working. I need help on how I can get this done.

```
<ListBox Name="QuestionsListBox" SelectionMode="Single" >
    <ListBox.Styles>
        <Style Selector="ListBoxItem:nth-child(odd)" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f0f5f9" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="ListBoxItem:nth-child(even)">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Styles>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="de:Questions">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="94" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding question}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding answer}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding marked}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding noted}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```